# Using declare and if statements in Oracle sql?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Hi I am havin gtrouble running this query. I am trying to get the input parameter and based on that value use it in the query.

The error I am getting is:

`**Error(26,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior **`

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE GET_STATES (
    i_id IN NUMBER,
    o_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,

IS

DECLARE country VARCHAR2 = '';

BEGIN
  o_sqlmsg  := 'SUCCESS';
  o_sqlcode := 0;

  IF i_id == 284 
    THEN country := 'US';
    ELSE country := 'CA';
  END IF;
  OPEN o_result FOR 
    Select cnint as Id, cnabbv as Code, rtrim(cnname) as Name, i_id as CId
    from country 
    order by cnname;
```

Comment: A closing bracket ')' here at `o_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)` , Also `DECLARE` keyword is not needed, when used to declare Procedures/Functions!

Comment: The equality operator is `=` in SQL (and PL/SQL). Not `==`. And you need to use a proper assignment operator `:=` in the variable declaration as well.

Comment: why bother with the if to set the value of country when you do not use it in the where?  Good idea not to name your variables with the same name as a table and better idea to tell Oracle how big your VARCHAR2 is going to be...as in DECLARE v_country VARCHAR2(2);

Comment: Please, study more about basic Oracle script syntax before asking a question.

Comment: Is `COUNTRY` the name of a table in your database, or are you expecting  that setting the variable `country` to `'US'` or `'CA'` will change the name of the table which is accessed by the `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure shouldn't have a `DECLARE` keyword in it and is missing its final END statement, along with a few other minor syntax problems. Change it to look something like

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE GET_STATES (i_id IN NUMBER,
                      o_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
  country VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
  o_sqlmsg  := 'SUCCESS';
  o_sqlcode := 0;

  IF i_id = 284 
    THEN country := 'US';
    ELSE country := 'CA';
  END IF;

  OPEN o_result FOR 
    Select cnint as Id,
           cnabbv as Code,
           rtrim(cnname) as Name,
           i_id as CId
    from country 
    order by cnname;
END GET_STATES;
```

Best of luck.